# Line plot of data by grouping rows

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I wish to plot a line plot of the df below by grouping the rows, so i would have 1 line for GDP, 1 line for agriculture and 1 line for services (ignoring countries for now), does anyone know if this is possible using ggplot?

My final plot would have an x axis of years and a y axis of gdp (value)

```
economics_df

Series Name              Country        1997        1998        1999        2000
GDP (current US$)        Spain   5.90077E+11 6.19215E+11 6.34908E+11 5.98363E+11
GDP (current US$)        France  1.45288E+12 1.50311E+12 1.49315E+12 1.36564E+12
GDP (current US$)        Monaco  2840175545  2934498443  2906093757  2647885849
GDP (current US$)        Italy   1.24188E+12 1.27005E+12 1.25245E+12 1.14668E+12
GDP (current US$)        Croatia 24091170703 25792876644 23677307509 21839780971
Agriculture  (% of GDP)  Spain   4.302210034 4.150411966 3.817378211 3.745305634
Agriculture (% of GDP)   France  2.344255815 2.362459834 2.236261411 2.098357551
Agriculture (% of GDP)   Monaco  2.544255815 2.342459834 2.234261411 2.108357551
Agriculture (% of GDP)   Italy   2.861911574 2.768857277 2.722232363  2.56361412
Agriculture (% of GDP)   Croatia 5.228986538 5.306173593 5.393085168 4.961600952
Services (% of GDP)      Syria   45.65197856 44.15290647 45.68986146 41.94697681
Services(% of GDP)       Lebanon 60.61030928 58.32727829 59.05884148 61.52190623
Services (% of GDP       Israel  62.02333939 63.02788655 63.92563162 64.72521236
Services (% of GDP)      Egypt   48.15193682 48.28789144 47.55581925 46.52599236
Services (% of GDP)      Libya   44.15193682 44.28789144 45.55581925 45.55581445
```

Comment: Before creating the right dataset for your ggplot, you may need to refine the modalities from variable `Series Name` (homogeneization)

Comment: Sure is this possible. First step would be to reshape your data using e.g. `tidyr::pivot_longer`. However as already noted by Yacine your data is a mix of percentages and dollar values and putting both in one plot will most likely not give a meaningful plot because of the different ranges and units.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get the data into the right shape. `ggplot` makes plotting very easy once the data is in long form, which is easy to do with `dplyr` and `tidyr`:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)

econ_for_plot  <- economics_df  |>
    pivot_longer(-c(`Series Name`, Country), names_to = "year")  |>
    group_by(`Series Name`, year)  |>
    summarise(value = sum(value))

econ_for_plot
# # A tibble: 12 x 3
# # Groups:   Series Name [3]   
#    `Series Name` year    value
#    <chr>         <chr>   <dbl>
#  1 Agriculture   1997  1.73e 1
#  2 Agriculture   1998  1.69e 1
#  3 Agriculture   1999  1.64e 1
#  4 Agriculture   2000  1.55e 1
#  5 GDP           1997  3.31e12
#  6 GDP           1998  3.42e12
#  7 GDP           1999  3.41e12
#  8 GDP           2000  3.14e12
#  9 Services      1997  2.61e 2
# 10 Services      1998  2.58e 2
# 11 Services      1999  2.62e 2
# 12 Services      2000  2.60e 2
```

I have used `sum()` in the `summarise()` call, but you could replace it with `mean()` or any other function to aggregate the data. Once it is in this form you can plot it:

```r
ggplot(econ_for_plot, 
    aes(
        x = year,
        y = value,
        color = `Series Name`,
        group = `Series Name`
    )
) +
    geom_point() +
    geom_line() +
    scale_y_log10() +
    labs(
        title = "Sum of spending",
        y = "Sum of category (log scale)"
    ) +
    theme_bw()
```

[image]

#### Input data

```r
economics_df <- structure(list(`Series Name` = c(
    "GDP", "GDP", "GDP", "GDP",
    "GDP", "Agriculture", "Agriculture", "Agriculture", "Agriculture",
    "Agriculture", "Services", "Services", "Services", "Services",
    "Services"
), Country = c(
    "Spain", "France", "Monaco", "Italy",
    "Croatia", "Spain", "France", "Monaco", "Italy", "Croatia", "Syria",
    "Lebanon", "Israel", "Egypt", "Libya"
), `1997` = c(
    5.90077e+11,
    1.45288e+12, 2840175545, 1.24188e+12, 24091170703, 4.302210034,
    2.344255815, 2.544255815, 2.861911574, 5.228986538, 45.65197856,
    60.61030928, 62.02333939, 48.15193682, 44.15193682
), `1998` = c(
    6.19215e+11,
    1.50311e+12, 2934498443, 1.27005e+12, 25792876644, 4.150411966,
    2.362459834, 2.342459834, 2.768857277, 5.306173593, 44.15290647,
    58.32727829, 63.02788655, 48.28789144, 44.28789144
), `1999` = c(
    6.34908e+11,
    1.49315e+12, 2906093757, 1.25245e+12, 23677307509, 3.817378211,
    2.236261411, 2.234261411, 2.722232363, 5.393085168, 45.68986146,
    59.05884148, 63.92563162, 47.55581925, 45.55581925
), `2000` = c(
    5.98363e+11,
    1.36564e+12, 2647885849, 1.14668e+12, 21839780971, 3.745305634,
    2.098357551, 2.108357551, 2.56361412, 4.961600952, 41.94697681,
    61.52190623, 64.72521236, 46.52599236, 45.55581445
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(
    NA,
    -15L
))
```

Edit: I made the Y-axis log-scale because the range of values was large. But now I have read the comments and looked at the data more closely, I realise that this plots absolute dollars and relative percent on the same scale. So this post tells you how to construct such a plot - although it does not really make sense to do so in this case.

Comment: What is the error message you get? That's just the code.

Comment: Yep apologies. This should be it - Error in `h()`:
! Problem with `summarise()` column `value`.
ℹ `value = sum(value)`.
✖ invalid 'type' (character) of argument
ℹ The error occurred in group 1: Series Name = "Agriculture (% of GDP)", year = "1997".

Comment: Right it's a character rather than numeric column so R doesn't know how to add it up. Try changing the line `summarise(value = sum(value))` to `summarise(value = sum(as.numeric(value), na.rm = T))` . A word of caution though that if you get a lot of warnings saying that `NAs were introduced by coercion` then make sure everything in that column is actually a number stored as text, rather than a string of characters.